# Get top 3 records form a IList +C#

Tags: c#

i have a iList  which has some records .I need to get  top 3 records from it . Is there any way to do this with 'LINQ'?

Comment: Define what you mean by "top 3." But the answer is generally "yes."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
IList<string> list = new List<string> { "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"};
var results = list.OrderBy(x => x).Take(3);
```

Comment: Thanks, when i try to bind this results  i am getting an error. "At least one object must implement IComparable." Do i need to implement IComparable????

Answer (score 6):

```
myList.OrderBy(i => {your criteria for "top" goes here}).Take(3);
```